# Getting httpresponse from other site

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, httpresponse, restsharp

Need help. I want to get the returned data from this link - http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfoSecurityProfile.html?method=getListedRecords&common=yes&ajax=true

However, if you copy and paste that link to your browser you get Access Denied ( See Tab Title). But if you paste this link first http://www.pse.com.ph ( load the page) then paste again the link above you data.

Here is my code. I am using RestSharp

```html
     
            string url = "http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfoSecurityProfile.html?method=getListedRecords&common=yes&ajax=true";

            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);

            var request = new RestRequest();      

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var strResult = response.Content;

            return Ok("OK");
```

It takes so much time getting the response from the site. Maybe because of the source site behavior?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the response of your site.
Try testing another way around.
Maybe due to the slow response, your host prevent the request.

Comment: What is the other way around?

Comment: Do you have a dummy site where you can retrieve the data? or try when a single value..

Comment: Im sorry. I did not get your point. I have no dummy site. What I am trying to do is to get the data returned from this link - http://www.pse.com.ph/stockMarket/companyInfoSecurityProfile.html?method=getListedRecords&common=yes&ajax=true

Comment: that is an external link and I have no access or whatsoever on that link. I just want get the returned data so I can manipulate it. Tnx